# Python perfect square alternative

Tags: python

I wrote this alternative to finding if a number was a perfect square or no how can I fix this:

```
n = input ('type n ')
message = ('false')
if n>0 and (math.sqrt(n)).is_integer(): message =  ('true') 
print (message)
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. Cast to `int`

Comment: `math.sqrt` is floating-point arithmetic, which is approximate.